# Adding image change effect jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following which loads three different images at an interval of 2.5 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imgsld = ['@Model.imageUrl[0]', '@Model.imageUrl[1]', '@Model.imageUrl[2]']
  var step = 0
  function slideit() {
    if (step < 3) {
      document.getElementById("slideimg").src = imgsld[step];
      step++;
    }
    else
      step = 0;
  }
  setInterval("slideit()", 2500)
</script>
```

I have it in my ASP.net MVC View.

How can I add a transition effect when the image changes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function slideit() {
if (step < 3) {
   $('#slideimg').fadeOut('slow',function(){
   $(this).attr('src',imgsld[step]).fadeIn('slow');
});

  step++;
}
else
  step = 0;
 }
```

Comment: i suggest you edit your original answer instead of posting a new one as it's very similar (almost the same)...

Comment: Instead of giving two answers you can modify your previous answer.

Comment: that was my mistake sorry to all of you next time i will

Comment: @RandomUser: Because he has used jQuery so it will not work as you are using pure JavaScript. You need to import jQuery file.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate I have imported them and the first cycle of images are getting displayed correctly with effect but after that I cant see the images

Comment: What image url you are giving is that correct?? I guess file should end with img.jpg or png or some extension...here your file name ends with @Model.imageUrl[0]

Comment: @ShoaibChikate its `Razor` code, I am storing the relative path of the image in a model and I am storing the urls of the images in an array using `@Model.imageUrl[0], 1 and 2`